# Observe rendering events

Tags: ember.js

Are there events that I can observe, similar to ember-data's events around data loading such as isLoaded/isUpdating, for while view/templates are being rendered?

I have a list of ~1000 elements going into a list, and it takes quite some time to even render (the topic of a whole other question). I'd like to show some indication to the user that rendering work is being done.

There are events at a more microcosmic level such as: http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.View.html#event_willClearRender. I'm curious to know if there are events for when *any* rendering is being performed.

Comment: Just to be clear, I already show a similar loading spinner for when data is being loaded from the adapter.

Answer (score 8):

`Ember.Instrumentation` provides a general purpose way to instrument code and conveniently, by default, Ember emits instrumentation events anytime something is rendered.

`Ember.subscribe` is used to setup a listener for before and after-- the events are namespaced with periods so subscribing to "render" will get you all render instrumentation calls, which by default is like "render.boundHandlebars", "render.metamorph", "render.view" ...

Here's a little function to help you get started.. you can paste this into the console and click around your app to check it out (or if you want to see all the rendering from the start paste it somewhere in your code so its loaded after ember but before your app).

If no event is passed to `beginInstrumentation` it'll default to `render` ...

```
beginInstrumentation = function(eventName) {
  var styles;
  if (eventName == null) {
    eventName = "render";
  }

  styles = {
    "render.render.metamorph": "color: #a47701;",
    "render.render.boundHandlebars": "color: #0f51fe;",
    "render.view": "color: #37be02;"
  };

  Ember.subscribe(eventName, {
    before: function(name, ts, payload) {
      console.group(name);
      return ts;
    },
    after: function(name, ts, payload, b_ts) {
      var elapsed, style;
      style = styles[name] || "";
      elapsed = (ts - b_ts).toFixed(4);
      console.log("%c" + payload.object + ": " + elapsed + "ms", style);
      return console.groupEnd();
    }
  });
};

beginInstrumentation();
```

Heres the output in chrome when I paste it into the TodoMVC app and click the all/completed/active filters (should work in firefox/firebug as well)

[image]

Comment: This is an excellent answer, and a fantastic demonstration. Thank you! I guess the follow-on question is: is showing/hiding a "spinner" an appropriate use of this instrumentation? It doesn't quite feel like it, but I could be wrong.

Comment: Ya that's a good question considering I'm not even 100% sure instrumentation is included in Ember's production build package (I'm thinking it is, as it's in ember-metal). I suppose it comes down to how you are doing things in your code-- it comes down to having a controller with a "loading" property, observe that property to determine if the loading spinner is displayed or not-- so how do you update that loading property? You have options.. override View.render if you need to.. do it based off any number of state transitions that views make.. override renderToBuffer.. instrumentation...

Comment: Just found an excellent post on this topic, check it out here: http://tobyho.com/2013/03/12/perf-testing-ember.js-views/