# How do I debug a mysterious pause in an Ember.js Application

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I have an ember.js application. It shows a list of "Problems". Once loaded, the first action taken to select (click) an individual item from this list has a 1-2 second delay. No delay is ever present on subsequent clicks.

The delay is not from the server, if I remove all content from the view/template, the delay is still present.

The delay is not in rendering. If I instrument the rendering process (as described in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15129150/1167846) nothing happens with rendering at all during that time, and the list displayed at the end shows nothing that indicates a multi-second pause.

If I use `console.log` all over the place, the click event appears to make all the necessary changes in my code (selecting the item as "current") without any delay.

How do I figure out where this delay is coming from?

Comment: Any chance you could add relevant/sample code to this question?

Comment: The question is more conceptual and the sample code has not been reducible and still reproduce the problem. I'm hoping there is some technique for debugging this sort of problem that I'm just missing. Sorry.

Comment: I'm working off of these slides at the moment to try to step through everything, but nothing stands out. https://speakerdeck.com/tomdale/debugging-emberjs

Comment: I see. Not sure if [this](http://alexmatchneer.com/blog/2013/01/12/everything-you-never-wanted-to-know-about-the-ember-run-loop/) is relevant, but maybe it could help

Comment: When does ember compile inline handlebars templates? Maybe this is compile time, when the template gets rendered for the first time?

Comment: I think I found something with the debugger. Inside of `Ember.tryFinally` on line 1104, the line `finalResult = finalizer.call(binding);` takes a long time, when stepping over it. I wonder what this does?

Comment: mavilein: good call! I'm pretty sure that using Rails 3.2 with the asset pipeline and ember-rails gem against master (details that I failed to share) has the handlebars templates pre-compiled when the page loads. The delay I'm experiencing is after the page is well done loading.